# bat file to copy a line from text file and paste it, then hit enter and repeat

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a list of names, I want bat file to copy first name (line) from the text file and paste, then hit enter, then copy the second name(line2) and paste, then again hit enter.

```
my list name examples:
@john will
@mark lu
@henry ford
```

I am not very good at programing to know technical stuff

Comment: Paste it where?

Comment: where ever the cursor is, example on a facebook comment in a browser, bat file runs in background and pstes names on facebook comments onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

THERE WAS THIS GUY HELPING ME OUT HERE BUT HE DELETED ALL HIS ANSWERS. STILL THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN. THE CODE YOU GAVE ME DID WORK OUT I ADDED 2-3 LINES
Solution:

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off

timeout /t 3

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~f0"
for /f "delims=" %%l in (c.txt) do (
echo %%l | clip
%SendKeys% "^{V}"
%SendKeys% "{LEFT}"
set /P "=Wait and send a command: " < NUL
timeout /t 1
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
)
Goto :eof

@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful in the end. Remember to check you own asnwer as an asnwer as well. This will help to keep the system clean.